# How to get refund details by it's ID using PayPal Java SDK

Tags: java, paypal

I'm trying to find an API call in PayPal Java SDK to pull refund details from the PayPal service. I have a transaction details and Refund id, but I can't find any API calls to get actual details of the Refund.
On PayPal developers' site I see only curl command, but not an SDK example for that operation. Am I missing something?

[Paypal refunds_get](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#refunds_get)

Comment: The API to get refund details is present in the link that you provided https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#refunds_get as `GET /v2/payments/refunds/{refund_id}`. Isn't that what you require?

Comment: @MadhuBhat We are using PayPal Java SDK (available on Maven) for all other operations, it will be rather strange to do this particular one via some kind of external class/library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the refund details using `GET /v2/payments/refunds/{refund_id}` API of PayPal as specified in the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#refunds_get) using any Http library.

Alternatively, if you want to exclusively use the PayPal's Java SDK itself, then you can use `RefundsGetRequest` object ([source](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Java-SDK/blob/master/checkout-sdk/src/main/java/com/paypal/payments/RefundsGetRequest.java)) present in the [Checkout-Java-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Java-SDK/tree/master) as below:

```
// Construct an environment with your client id and secret"
PayPalEnvironment environment = new PayPalEnvironment.Sandbox("xxxx","xxxx");

// Use this environment to construct a PayPalHttpClient
PayPalHttpClient client = new PayPalHttpClient(environment);

String refundId = "1234"; //set the refundId with the right value
String authorization = "xxxx" //The auth value would be Bearer <Access-Token> or Basic <client_id>:<secret>

// Construct a request object and set the desired parameters.
RefundsGetRequest request = new RefundsGetRequest(refundId)
                                 .authorization(authorization);

try {
    // Use your client to execute a request and get a response back
    HttpResponse<Refund> refundResponse = client.execute(request);

    // If the endpoint returns a body in its response, you can access the deserialized 
    // version by calling result() on the response.
    Refund refundDetails = refundResponse.result();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    if (ioe instanceof HttpException) {
        // Something went wrong server-side
        HttpException he = (HttpException) ioe);
        int statusCode = he.getStatusCode();
        String debugId = he.getHeaders().header("PayPal-Debug-Id");
    } else {
        // Something went wrong client-side
    }
}
```

The catch block shown above is inline with the SDK documentation's generic example, but ideally it would be better to handle it as below:

```
catch (HttpException ex) {
    // Something went wrong server-side
    int statusCode = ex.getStatusCode();
    String debugId = ex.getHeaders().header("PayPal-Debug-Id");
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle accordingly
}
```

Link of Maven repository for the checkout-sdk is [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.paypal.sdk/checkout-sdk)

Comment: Good answer but I would have put a separate catch clause for HttpException.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException yes I know the catch block doesn't look good, but that is in line with the SDK documentation example, and I didn't modify it for brevity.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException have added an update. Would that be fine? :)

Comment: Thanks. Is this version of SDK an official release already? Is it available on Maven?

Comment: @AndreyLebedenko yes I've added the maven repo link in my answer.

Comment: @MadhuBhat Aha! That's the one. Thanks. Strange that we are back to handling all HTTP related stuff again, but... well... this is it. Thanks again.

Comment: The separate catch block is better, but `HttpException he = (HttpException) ioe);` doesn't make sense as you haven't got a variable called `ioe` any more; instead you have `ex` which is already an `HttpException` and therefore you don't need to cast it.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException oops my bad! Corrected it.